# voltage drop alternative to resistor

Tags: voltage

My application requires me to drop voltage from 12v to 6v or any other lower voltage.

I have used resistors but they are not efficient for prolonged use as they tend to heat up and burn my fuse.
I want to know whether there are any other IC or a simple circuit which 'll be small in size, inexpensive, efficient and does not heat up much to cause problem.

Comment: AC or DC voltage? If AC, phase difference matters? If DC, will the voltage be fixed or varying? You have to specify more details.

Comment: How much current are you going to draw?

Comment: a repeat of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127525/reducing-voltage-with-resistors/127538#127538

Answer (score 4):

I presume this would be for a power supply?  If the voltage drop from 12v to 6v releases too much heat, then I would recommend using a DC to DC converter of some sort.  A linear regulator is basically just a glorified resistor, so converting 12V to 6V would make a linear converter 50% efficient.  A switching power supply can be 70% to 90+% efficient, and as a result will produce far less heat.  A buck power supply would be the way to go, and you can either build one yourself with an off-the-shelf controller chip or just buy a complete module.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regulator for this with heat sink and you have 6volt constant in output.

Comment: Just like alex said in his answer, "a linear regulator is basically just a glorified resistor".  You still have heat equal to the power loss = current * (voltage drop).

Comment: so you can use LED or motor with good efficiency so Additional power convert to light or mechanical energy not heat.

Comment: if you do that, then the resulting voltage will not be well-defined.  And you will still be converting some of the difference to heat.  Maybe this is OK, but generally you want a power supply that doesn't change voltage with changing conditions (e.g. mechanical load, or more commonly just variations in current draw).  A DC to DC converter will convert power in to power out with a very stable output and (relatively) little loss.  For a step down, you will get more current out than the converter will draw.  For 12v to 6v, a 1A load on the output might draw 550 mA on the input (~90% efficient).