# How to drop 230V AC TO 200V AC

Tags: voltage

Is there any way to drop 230V AC  to 200 V AC by using resistor? I want to drop voltage before applying to a 12 0 12V 500mA transformer. If yes what will be its rating?

Comment: The answer to this question ([Reducing voltage with resistors](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127525/)) applies: It only works if the load current is predictable and constant. A better solution is to choose a regulated "transformer" that is capable of accepting 200 V input.

Comment: You might be able to get away with a 6.8µF high voltage (eg. 275VAC MPX/MKP) bipolar series capacitor, but it highly depends on your load. A capacitor may work in some cases, but certainly not all.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with another transformer. A 230vAC:30VAC connected to oppose the voltage will work. However you could also replace the transformer since it is only a small (12VA) transformer.

If you are trying to adapt a Japanese standard product to 230VAC you may find that there are primary taps on the transformer that you can use.

Using a resistor is not a good idea generally because the voltage drop will vary with loading.