# How to convert 9v supply to 5v?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, battery-operated, breadboard

I am making half adder circuit for my school project but I saw their datasheet and it says maximum supply volate is 5.25v and I have 9v battery, How do I use it if I want to test my circuit without burning ICS?
I watched this video to complete my project but he didn't specify the battery he used. Pls help
Video link -: https://youtu.be/rNG_KD1hfpc. Thank you
IC I used : Ic 7408(SN74LS08N) , IC 7432 (SN74LS32N), IC 7404 (SN74LS04N) . thank you

Comment: Google "Voltage Regulator".

Comment: In fact the first answer to this question should tell you all you need to know: [Reducing voltage with resistors](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127525/reducing-voltage-with-resistors). Took all of 10 seconds to find using the search box at the top.

Answer (score 0):

For low power load applications (such as your case) you could use voltage regulator
https://www.soselectronic.com/productdata/17/71/6/17716/L78S.pdf

For more demanding devices use switching step-down regulator
https://www.soselectronic.com/productdata/93/80/4/93804/ltc1767.pdf

Take the links as example only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a power supply to convert 9V to 5V, there are other alternatives.  You can get a 5v wall mount PS at your local supermarket for about $10.  That is, don't use batteries, but, if you must, your circuit will probably work with three 1.5 volt batteries in series.  A real longshot solution would be to use different ICs.  The original 4000 series CMOS ICs worked with Vdd 5 to 15 volts and many types are still available. They might be hard to find, and they probably would have different pinouts.